Describing proof of number of permutations of $n$ distinct objects
Have just started learning about TLA.  I am trying to write a proof about computing the permutations of $n$ distinct objects.
A proof would follow in this way
My proof starts by first selecting a ball from $n$ balls. There are n possibilities because there aro n distinct objects to choose from.
For the second choice, after choosing the first item, there are $n-1$ remaining objects available for the second choice, since one item has already been chosen.
Similarly for the continued choice, there is one fewer object available to choose from.
For the final choice, by the time of the final choice is made, one item remains.
Let S = {a1,a2,...,an}
c1 \in S => |S| = n
c2 \in S\{c1} => |S\{c1}| = n-1
ck \in S\{c1,c2,...,c{k-1}} => |S\{c1,c2,...,c{k-1}}| = n-(k-1)
cn \in S\{c1,c2,...,c{n-1}} => |S\{c1,c2,...,c{n-1}}| = 1

Thus Permutations(S) = n!

Have looked at the Temporal Logic of Actions (TLA) of Leslie Lamport.  Would like to see how I can describe this theorem  using TLA.  There is not much wark on proving mathematical theoroms using TLA, because it is mostly used in computing to describe behaviours of concurrent and distributed systems.

The question is unclear. What is TLA? Your proof outline is so vague it is not even clear what statement you would like to prove.

The Temporal Logic of Actions of Leslie Lamport.

Please edit your question so that it contains enough information for people to be able to tell what you're talking about.

Is there a reason why you want to use TLA specifically? As you say, this is a proof assistant designed for a specific software correctness task, rather than general mathematics, so it might be ill-suited to combinatorics.

Have seen Leslie Lamport describe his method of proof in https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/proof.pdf and want to do the same.  See pages 24 and 25.  As a way to write a proof but not designed for a specific implementation of a correctness prover such as Coq.

@Djoser  To use TLA in a proof assistant, you'd have first to formalize TLA.  That said, you seem to be rather asking about proving termination (of some computation, in some proof assistant), which I think is altogether a different question, one that strictly speaking has nothing to do with issues of temporality.  Maybe you can clarify?

Lamport had given an example of using TLA to make mathematical proofs.  But most of his work has been on computation.  To test whether a mathematical proof is correct, I would need something  like Coq rather than TLA+, which is focused upon algorithms.
